# Resteasy multiple resource path waring

Tags: spring, resteasy

I have a service class with 2 GET request like following and in the log is is always giving me warning about **Multiple resource method match Request**

```
@Path("/a")
class Service{
    @Path("/{name}"
    @GET
    public A methodA(@PathParam("name") String name){return a;}

    @Path("/status")
    @GET
    public B methodB(){return b;}
}
```

Can anybody have any idea why is that??
I am using rest-easy version **3.0.8** with spring **4.x.x**

Comment: `/status` isnt the same as `/{name}` where you pass the string `status` in the `PathParam` `name`?

Comment: when you hit url '/a/status' where do you want your application go to? lets say when name = 'status'

Comment: Thanks for the comments. It works the way it is implemented now but **my question is why it is throwing warning for this??** I didn't get that. One is static path and another is variable path. And also one resource method has argument and another does not.

Answer (score 0):

Considering my comment in your question above, I would rewrite my controller to this:

```
@Path("/a")
class Service{
            @Path("/{name}"
            @GET
            public ResponseEntity methodA(@PathParam("name") String name){
                if("status".equals(name) {
                  return new ResponseEntiry(b, OK);
                } else {
                    return new ResponseEntiry(a, OK);
                }
            }
}
```